# Percent Change Question

Tags: percentages

**If 150 were increased by 60% and then decreased by y%, the result would be 192. What is the value of y?**

My solution is to use percent change. Here are my steps and yet my answer is incorrect. Can someone please advise why my answer is incorrect? Thanks.

1. $150 * 0.60 = 90$
2. $150 + 90 = 240$
3. Percent change = ((New value − Old value) /Old value) $∗ 100$
4. New value = $240$, Old Value = $192$
5. $((240-192)/192)*100 = 25$

Comment: You say to divide by the old value, but you are using 192, which is the new value. The new value is 192, while the old value is 240.

Comment: The correct answer is 20%, as you can check by plugging the correct values

Answer (score 2):

"Increasing by 60%" is multiplying by $1.60$.

"Decreasing by $y$%" is mutiplying by $1-\tfrac{y}{100}$.

You know that $150(1.60)(1-\tfrac{y}{100}) = 192$.

So, solving for $y$, the desired percentage is $y = 100\left(1 - \dfrac{192}{150(1.60)}\right) = \boxed{20}$.

Answer (score -1):

to increase by 60% you multiply by 1,6 so you get 240 wich you did
to decrease bei y% yo u multiply by 1-y/100
so you have 240*(1-y/100)=192
1-(y/100)=192/240=0.8 so y is 0.2*100=20
your kind of reasoning 240-192=48 but 240 is the old value, 192 the new, and 48 is 20% of 240  or 48/240=0.2=20%

Comment: This is almost impossible to read, perhaps because it was written on a phone.

Comment: Eek, my brain hurts